# Gradle project sync completed with some errors (Cannot sync)

Tags: android, compilation, dependencies, repository, android-gradle-plugin

I have an error with my build.gradle. I try to link to the Github project but it failed.

build.gradle(Project:XXXX)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
          //mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://maven/jjhesk" }
       jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://maven/jjhesk" }
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle(Module:XXXX)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.testingtimer"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    /* compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })*/
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.pheynix:TimerView:660400fb64'
    //androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I try to follow these instructions which is in this website:

- https://github.com/pheynix/TimerView/blob/master/README_ENGLISH.md
- https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel

Could someone help me to solve the problem?

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: @sanastasiadis Error(1,0) Could not get unknown property 'build' for root project

Comment: Question: do you have `build.gradle(Project:XXXX)` as the first line of the build.gradle of your root project? You shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error today. To fix that, I opened **build.gradle** file and replaced the **2** occurences of:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

By

```
repositories {
    maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com" }
    jcenter()
}
```

In my case the problem was caused by the **proxy**. It has problems with **https** then I'm forcing the use of **http**.